# LNK1181: Visual Studio cannot find object file

Tags: visual-studio

I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.9.29` when compiling a project.
Compilation goes well, but linker shows an error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open
> "H:\work\build\Release_x64\intermediate\plugin\Helper.obj"

I checked the file. It does not exist. Any reasonable thought would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

/P compiler option was on, and object files were not generated.